# Async facebook buttons

Tags: facebook, asynchronous

I want a like button on my page. To share the page. When you click on the like button. He must post on the facebook wall. A custom post with a link. How can i make this with facebook.

The problem is. I want two like buttons with different text and url on the site. How can i do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking for is Share button, not like (there is no text/message in like button)
 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/
You specify url to share like this

```
<a name="fb_share" type="button" share_url="YOUR URL GOES HERE"></a> 
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

You can specify description/text useng Open Graph https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

```
<meta property="og:description" content="Blah blah bla" />
```

This, howver, has nothing to do with asynchronous loading of script, so I'm not really sure what you're asking for. Hope this helps at least a bit.